# Mustach loop through Obj containing Array containing Obj

Tags: javascript, object, mustache

I have an Object containing Arrays containing Objects
**Example:**

```
main: {
  arr1: [
    obj1: {x: 0, y: 0},
    obj2: {x: 0, y: 0}
  ],
  arr2: [
    obj3: {x: 0, y: 0},
    obj4: {x: 0, y: 0}
  ]
}
```

I need with **Mustach** to retrieve all the x values of those objects (obj1 - 4).
Every object and array can have a random name.

**I tried:**

```
{{#main}}
  {{#.}}
    {{x}}
  {{/.}}
{{/main}}
```

But it's not working.
Anyone have an idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, when a section refers to an object, the properties of the object are exposed inside the section, but there is not iteration. So in the section {{#main}}, arr1 and arr2 are exposed, and {{#arr1}} would iterate the array.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I'm not getting any result at all :S

Comment: because {{#.}} refers to the main object that has no property x

Comment: Thank you, now I understand, but is there any workaround I can do in my case ?

Comment: You can make two subsections of main {{#arr1}} and {{#arr2}}, but if you don't know what properties main will have, the only solution I can think of it to transorm your objects before applying the template. Mustach is very limited; it can be frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

None of those things in your example are arrays, they're all objects. Arrays have 0-indexed consecutive numeric keys. That's all you can iterate over in Mustache.

If you want to iterate over the values of objects, you should prepare your data before passing it off to Mustache. Something like Underscore.js's `_.values` function is super useful for that.

Comment: I might be wrong, but arr1 and arr2 are not associative arrays?

Comment: There's no such thing as an "associative array" in JavaScript. Just arrays (non-associative) and objects.